# Firefox scroll bars but not on Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, google-chrome

I'm having trouble finding where I have the CSS wrong on this site. On Firefox, it's showing side scrolling to the right but on Chrome, it looks fine. I'm thinking `overflow:hidden;` but I can't seem to find where to put that.

Here's the site: http://www.llmedia.co/

Appreciate it!

Comment: Your site has significant syntax errors which should be fixed before assuming this discrepancy is the browsers' fault. http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your footer. Your whole page width is 960px. But the footer ul width is 1100px.  So in small screens your site will have a scroll bar to the right. Same result will happen in firefox browser too. So reduce the footer width to 960px and your scroll bar will disappear!

```
#footer ul { width: 960px; }
```

Comment: Welcome. If your problem solved, then you can mark this answer as accepted. Check this [link faq section](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) to know about reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I see a scrollbar in Chrome so I'm guessing it has to do with your viewport size. Try shrinking your browser window in Chrome and see what happens. Be careful with using `overflow:hidden;`. You may be hiding content from users who don't have a large viewport for whatever reason.